# Alunos com o último comparecimento >15 dias por mês

Tags: mysql

Preciso de uma query que mostre quais os alunos que possuem +15 dias de seu último comparecimento na escola. Preciso encontrar as evasões por mês (quantos alunos e quais alunos foram por mês).

**Ex:**
Em Janeiro, o último comparecimento do aluno "x" já possui +15 dias. Logo, posso considerá-lo uma evasão de Janeiro e assim para todos os meses seguintes...

Por gentileza, poderiam me auxiliar?

**Obs:** Não sei se estou no caminho certo, mas pensei em deixar a query abaixo como uma "temp" e agrupar a consulta de fora por "MONTH(alu.data_cad)" e "alu.cod".

Query para análise:

```
(       SELECT 
                 es.codigo_marca
                ,es.codigo_escola
                ,alu.cod
                ,alu.cod_sis
                ,DATE_FORMAT(alu.data_cad, '%d-%m-%Y') AS data_cad
                ,DATE_FORMAT(
                        (SELECT MAX(ca.data_comparecimento)
                            FROM Marcacao mc
                               INNER JOIN ComparecimentoAlu ca ON ca.codigo_marcacao = mc.codigo_marcacao
                                                                                                  AND mc.dt_reposicao IS NULL
                           WHERE mc.codigo_csc = cc.cod_csc), '%d-%m-%Y') AS ultimo_comparecimento
                ,ac.codigo_tp_ac
                ,es.cod_rg_escola
                ,es.cod_cl_escola
                ,cc.cod_csc
        FROM
                Aln alu
                INNER JOIN Acd ac ON alu.cod = ac.alu_cod
                INNER JOIN Esc es ON ac.codigo_escola = es.codigo_escola AND ac.data_del IS NULL
                INNER JOIN CsCont cc ON cc.codigo_acd = ac.codigo
        WHERE
                YEAR(alu.data_cad) = 2022
                AND es.codigo_escola IN (5,6,7,8,9,10)
        GROUP BY alu.cod
        ORDER BY alu.data_cad ASC
)
```

Desde já, agradeço a todos!

Comment: A subquery de ' marcacao' que está como coluna eu colocaria como uma tabela virtual join com o max(data) e testando no where .... ou .... testar a condição da data em um NOT EXISTS

Comment: @Motta, 

Tentei aqui utilizando um DATEADD com intervalo de três semanas, dentro de uma subquery e depois com um CASE WHEN fora, e aparentemente deu certo. Mas, obrigado por sua grande ajuda, meu amigo!

Abraços!